# Password Protect a Podcast Feed?

Tags: feed, podcasting

I've got a Wordpress account that I have multiple users on. I want to create a podcast feed that only those users have access to. Is there any method or plugin that could do this?

Answer (score -1):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-post-privacy/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/show-private/

Either of these would work, depending on how you want to share the posts.